# Using list values to determine which one is a parent and which one is a child

Tags: python

How would I go about converting this

```
[
    [1, '025', ...],
    [1, '026', ...],
    [2, '027', ...],
    [2, '028', ...],
    [3, '029', ...],
    [3, '030', ...],
    [2, '031', ...],
    [2, '032', ...],
]
```

into this

```
[
    [1, None, '025', ...],
    [1, None, '026', ...],
    [2, '026', '027', ...],
    [2, '026','028', ...],
    [3, '028','029', ...],
    [3, '028','030', ...],
    [2, '026','031', ...],
    [2, '026','032', ...],
]
```

the new addition (2nd element in all) being the parent number of it based on the first element.
if you need any more details or information, let me know (this me first time asking a question)

Comment: Can you explain your question??

Comment: so basically the first number in each of those lists represents its indentation and i want to make it so for example if its 1, its a parent to 2

Comment: Well...I still didn't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is a possible two-step solution. Note that I made the input list have only two elements, you should try modifying it for multielement case to better understand the program,

```
raw_list = [[1, '025'], [1, '026'],
                [2, '027'], [2, '028'],
                [3, '029'], [3, '030'],
                [2, '031'], [2, '032']]

with_parents = []

# Find all parents (second sublist with the
#   the same first element)
# first element converted to string : [second element, counter]
parent_dict = {}
for elem in raw_list:
    el_id = str(elem[0])
    if el_id in parent_dict:
        # Check the counter, replace if second
        if parent_dict[el_id][1] == 1:
            parent_dict[el_id][1] += 1
            parent_dict[el_id][0] = elem[1]
        else:
            continue
    else:
        # If there is only one occurence, this persists 
        parent_dict[el_id] = [elem[1], 1]

# Create the parent - child list
for elem in raw_list:
    # ID of the parent
    p_id = str(elem[0]-1)
    # No parents
    if p_id == '0':
        with_parents.append([elem[0], None, elem[1]])
    else:
        # Look up and insert parent and child info
        with_parents.append([elem[0], parent_dict[p_id][0], elem[1]])
```

In the first step, the code collects information about the parents into a dictionary. There are various ways to do it, more efficient too. Here we iterate through the whole list and simply gather the second element of each
ID (first entry in the sublist). The ID becomes the dictionary key, and the
dictionary entry stores the parent value you want to use later, and a counter. The counter indicates if the already stored value is the second entry in the `raw_list`. The dictionary makes it convenient to access parent
data later on, and it makes it valid for discontinuous IDs (like if you have
1,2,3, 5, 6 - i.e. missing a 4).

In the second step the code builds the final parent-child list. It iterates through the list again, this time looking up the right parent in the dictionary built in step 1. It saves the parent and child information into another list, the final one, `with_parents`. It treats the entries with `ID = 1` as special cases.

Note that if there is only one entry for a parent in the `raw_list`, that will be the entry used in the `with_parents` list.

Comment: thanks for the help! i know the question wasn't very well explained, but thank you

Comment: Gladly! :) If you want to be clearer next time, I think you can just make the example more detailed (like explain what do you mean by second element etc.). Also, it's best if you show us what you tried, even if you think its not great. It makes it easier to help :)